# The name lookup for "__rotatel4" did not find a declaration

Tags: c++, aix, intrinsics, xlc

I'm working on GCC111 from the compile farm. The machine is AIX 7.1, POWER7 with IBM XLC 12.1. I'm trying to use `__rotatel4`:

```
$ cat test.cxx
#include <cstdlib>

unsigned int Foo (unsigned int x)
{
  return __rotatel4(x, 4U);
}
```

A compile results in:

```
$ xlC -O3 -c test.cxx
"test.cxx", line 5.10: 1540-0274 (S) The name lookup for "__rotatel4" did not find a declaration.
```

According to the compiler manual [IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024204) (p. 486) the intrinsics should be available. Here is the prototype, and it does not have restrictions like POWER6:

```
unsigned int __rotatel4 (unsigned int rs, unsigned int shift)
```

Adding `-qarch=pwr7` and/or `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` resulted in the same error. I found [Unexpected name lookup error "1540-0274 (S)" when compiling code with templates](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21315623), but it does not seem to apply here.

How does one use `__rotatel4` in a program?

---

```
gcc111$ oslevel -s
7100-03-02-1412

gcc111$ xlC -qversion
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1 (5765-J02, 5725-C72)
Version: 12.01.0000.0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For XL C/C++ V12.1, you'll need to include `<builtins.h>`:

```
$ cat aaa.cpp
#include <cstdlib>

unsigned int Foo (unsigned int x)
{
  return __rotatel4(x, 4U);
}
$ xlC aaa.cpp -c
"aaa.cpp", line 5.10: 1540-0274 (S) The name lookup for "__rotatel4" did not find a declaration.
$ cat aaa.cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <builtins.h>

unsigned int Foo (unsigned int x)
{
  return __rotatel4(x, 4U);
}
$ xlC aaa.cpp -c
$
```

For the upcoming 16.1 release, which is in beta, you don't need it.  (It will work with and without it.)

Comment: Thanks again @Rafik. What, exactly, does `__rotatel4` do? The description says *"Rotate Left Word"* but does not say more. I thought it was an intrinsic for a customary C rotate, but judging from the number of failed self tests it does something else.

Comment: It rotates the first argument by the number of arguments specified by the second argument.  Here is an example:

```#include <stdio.h>
#include <builtins.h>

int main() {
  unsigned int a, b, c;
      a = 0xabcdef01;
      for (int i=0; i < 8; ++i) {
        b = __rotatel4(a, 4 * i);
        printf("0x%08x\n", b);
      }
  return 0;
}```

Prints:

```0xabcdef01
0xbcdef01a
0xcdef01ab
0xdef01abc
0xef01abcd
0xf01abcde
0x01abcdef
0x1abcdef0```